# how to set cookie in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I am trying to use Zend Framework to set a cookie but I don't understand how it works.

```
$cookie = md5("_somerandomstring_");

Zend_Loader::loadClass("Zend_Http_Client");

require_once "Zend/Http/Cookie.php";

$client = new Zend_Http_Client();

$cookie = new Zend_Http_Cookie('foo', $cookie, '.mydomain.com', time()+7200, '/path');

$client->setCookieJar();
$client->setCookie($cookie);
```

How can I set the `.mydomain.com` when I am run my site on `localhost`?

Comment: And what is your problem? `$cookie = new Zend_Http_Cookie('foo', $cookie, '.mydomain.com', time()+7200, '/path');` is a correct.

Comment: Very difficult answering your non question there. What is wrong? Is it that you dont know how to retrieve the cookies?

Comment: but i am work on localhost so how i can set domain name? please help me

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i am run my project on localhost so how can i set domain name in 3rd argument of Zend_Http_Cookies()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the domain as an environment-specific config entry in `application/configs/application.ini`.

```
[production]
cookieDomain = "example.com"

[development:production]
cookieDomain = "localhost"
```

Then use that domain as the third arg in `Zend_Http_Cookie` constructor.

This way, when running in development mode, you can set the domain to be "localhost", while running in production, you can set it to be, say, "example.com".

Note: I'd still use a virtual-host - named something like "example.local" - for running locally in dev mode. For example, if you were developing two different projects using "localhost", cookies that you set for those two projects on that single domain could suffer from name-collision.